# Why is ても used here?

Tags: translation, て-form, particle-も

> お前　何を

And his answer

> 縛り上げるだけだよ

> まだ襲われてもうっとうしいから

I understand he's expressing his displeasure over the possibly of another attack, but why is "も" particle used?